# How to find xpath or to findelement of tag input and type='image' in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to automate a web application in which I'm facing a problem. The problem is I want to click a button which is Export button which will ask to export in to pdf or Excel. While inspecting I can find the element but while running the script it is not clicking the button. The button is having tag `input` and type `image`.

I've tried with different xpaths like below and also I've tried absolute xpath which is not clicking on the button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='exportReport']")).click();
```

and

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='exportReport']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='exportReport']")).click();
```

```html
<td width="15px">
<input type = "image" name="exportReport" src="birt/images/ExportReport.gif title="Export report" alt="Export report" class="birtviewer_clickable">
</td>
```

This Tag is not `img` tag but the type is `image`.

I'm getting:

> "Element click Intercepted", "NosuchelementException".

Comment: what is your browser and it's version?

Comment: Are you getting `Element click Intercepted` or `NosuchelementException`?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and the version is 75.0.3770.142

Comment: Now i'm getting NosuchelementException.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems you were close. As you are trying to `click()` on the element instead of *EC* as `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to use `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.birtviewer_clickable[name='exportReport'][src^='birt/images/ExportReport'][alt='Export report']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='birtviewer_clickable' and @name='exportReport'][starts-with(@src, 'birt/images/ExportReport') and @alt='Export report']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Hi, When i'm trying this it is showing "org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException:"

Comment: @sai Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your element is not within an `iframe` if so, you have to first switch into the `iframe` and then perform the action. If not, give a try with the below code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("exportReport"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below given code snippet

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf( 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@src='birt/images/ExportReport.gif']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@src='birt/images/ExportReport.gif']")).click();
```